# Go through all the objects (except the table) of a worksheet, and print its type

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a VBA program that parses **all the elements** of a worksheet except the 2-dimensional data table.

That means, I want to go through all the charts, buttons, checkboxs, etc. if they exist. I would like this list to be **exhaustive**. So the 1st question is what collections to go through.

One option is `ActiveSheet.Shapes`, another option is `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects`, I don't know if there is anything else... Could anyone tell me which one covers everything?

Once an item is identified, I want to determine if it is a chart, button, checkbox... I realize that the following code doesn't achieve it: it prints always `Shape`.

```
For Each sShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    MsgBox TypeName(sShape)
Next
```

Does anyone know how to show the type of an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from MSDN ([Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835842%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [OLEObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838421%28v=office.15%29.aspx)):

***OLEObject Object:***

> Represents an ActiveX control or a linked or embedded OLE object on a worksheet.

***Shape:***

> Represents an object in the drawing layer, such as an AutoShape, freeform, OLE object, or picture.

So, `ActiveSheet.Shapes` *include* `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects`.

Both collections doesn't include [Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx), which are part of [`ListObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195678%28v=office.15%29.aspx) collection.

So, you want `Shapes` collection. Following code prints types of all shapes in active sheet:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As Shape

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print "Type: " & s.Type & "  Name: " & s.Name
        If s.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            Debug.Print "     OleObject Type: " & TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object.Object)
        ElseIf s.Type = msoFormControl Then
            Debug.Print "     FormControl Type: " & s.FormControlType
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Possible output of subroutine:**

> ```
> Type: 3  Name: Chart 1
> Type: 1  Name: Rectangle 2
> Type: 12 Name: CheckBox1
>       OleObject Type: CheckBox
> Type: 8  Name: Button 2
>       FormControl Type: 0
> ```

**Notes:**

1. `s.Type` represents type of `Shape` object and returns [MsoShapeType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432678%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
2. if `s.Type = msoOLEControlObject` (*OleObject*), part `TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object.Object)` returns *name* of `OleObject` type, like "CheckBox", "Button" and etc.
3. if `s.Type = msoFormControl` (*Form* control), part `s.FormControlType` returns [XlFormControl Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841169%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: It took me a little while to find the listings of properties of the objects, but this page should be a good start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry Pavliv, whose answer i cannot upvote due to limitations.

Because the numeric values for `s.Type` and `s.FormControlType` are not verbose enough for me, I added two explanatory arrays like this:

```
Sub ShapeTypeEnumeration()
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547323/go-through-all-the-objects-except-the-table-of-a-worksheet-and-print-its-type#23548773
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim XlFormControlType(9) As String
    XlFormControlType(0) = "xlButtonControl": XlFormControlType(1) = "xlCheckBox": XlFormControlType(2) = "xlDropDown"
    XlFormControlType(3) = "xlEditBox": XlFormControlType(4) = "xlGroupBox": XlFormControlType(5) = "xlLabel"
    XlFormControlType(6) = "xlListBox": XlFormControlType(7) = "xlOptionButton": XlFormControlType(8) = "xlScrollBar"
    XlFormControlType(9) = "xlSpinner"
    Dim MsoShapeTypes(33) As String ' CAUTION: correct MsoShapeType is result of Shape.Type + 2, because msoShapeTypeMixed = -2, msoAutoShape = 1, ...
    MsoShapeTypes(0) = "msoShapeTypeMixed": MsoShapeTypes(3) = "msoAutoShape": MsoShapeTypes(4) = "msoCallout": MsoShapeTypes(5) = "msoChart"
    MsoShapeTypes(6) = "msoComment": MsoShapeTypes(7) = "msoFreeform": MsoShapeTypes(8) = "msoGroup": MsoShapeTypes(9) = "msoEmbeddedOLEObject"
    MsoShapeTypes(10) = "msoFormControl": MsoShapeTypes(11) = "msoLine": MsoShapeTypes(12) = "msoLinkedOLEObject": MsoShapeTypes(13) = "msoLinkedPicture"
    MsoShapeTypes(14) = "msoOLEControlObject": MsoShapeTypes(15) = "msoPicture": MsoShapeTypes(16) = "msoPlaceholder": MsoShapeTypes(17) = "msoTextEffect"
    MsoShapeTypes(18) = "msoMedia": MsoShapeTypes(19) = "msoTextBox": MsoShapeTypes(20) = "msoScriptAnchor": MsoShapeTypes(21) = "msoTable"
    MsoShapeTypes(22) = "msoCanvas": MsoShapeTypes(23) = "msoDiagram": MsoShapeTypes(24) = "msoInk": MsoShapeTypes(25) = "msoInkComment"
    MsoShapeTypes(26) = "msoIgxGraphic": MsoShapeTypes(27) = "msoSlicer": MsoShapeTypes(28) = "msoWebVideo": MsoShapeTypes(29) = "msoContentApp"
    MsoShapeTypes(30) = "msoGraphic": MsoShapeTypes(31) = "msoLinkedGraphic": MsoShapeTypes(32) = "mso3DModel": MsoShapeTypes(33) = "msoLinked3DModel"

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print "Type: " & MsoShapeTypes(s.Type + 2) & "  Name: " & s.Name
        If s.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            Debug.Print "     OleObject Type: " & TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object.Object)
        ElseIf s.Type = msoFormControl Then
            Debug.Print "     FormControl Type: " & XlFormControlType(s.FormControlType)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Possible Output:**

```
Type: msoChart  Name: Chart 1
Type: msoAutoShape  Name: Rectangle 2
Type: msoOLEControlObject Name: CheckBox1
      OleObject Type: CheckBox
Type: msoFormControl  Name: Button 2
      FormControl Type: xlButtonControl
```

It's in principle the same code like Dmitry's, but with descriptions instead of values of the included enumerations `XlFormControl` and `MsoShapeType`.