# Loop counter in checkbox name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a sheet which will have a checkbox in each non-empty line. To automatically adjust the number of checkboxes I created this macro:

```
Sub checkboxes()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 9 To 200
Set CurCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
    If CurCell.Value > 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox" & CStr(i)).Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox" & CStr(i)).Visible = False
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I expect number of potential rows with data not greater than 200. Macro checks if value in column C for each line is >1, if true checkbox is visible, else it's hidden.

My problem is that I don't know how to put the loop counter "i" into Shape name - I got an error using code above. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Make sure your checkboxes are called CheckBox9, CheckBox10...

Comment: Checkboxes are named properly. The error I am getting is "The item with specified name wasn't found".

Comment: Agreed - When I add a new checkbox, the name comes through with spaces, eg. `Check Box 1`, so you calling out `"Checkbox" & CStr(i)` won't find anything, unless you manually changed the names of each checkbox.

Comment: Maybe one of them doesn't exist. Check the value of i when that error happens, and then go check that checkbox exists.

Comment: Code looks fine in my opinion. I bet it's something with the checkboxes names

Comment: please check with the check box name as suggested by @theguythatdoesntknowmuch. Try leaving space before and after box

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Indeed, I didn't change a name of one of the checkboxes... Case solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a more elegant solution.

This loops through all shapes on `ActiveSheet` and checks if they are a `msoOLEControlObject` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547323/go-through-all-the-objects-except-the-table-of-a-worksheet-and-print-its-type) for more information on that matter).

```
Sub checkboxes()

Dim curCellValue as Variant
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            curCellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
            If curCellValue <> "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = True
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

So why is this "better"?

1. You don't have to "guess" how many values there will be.
2. If you ever change a name of a CheckBox this script will still be working.
3. This checks for *empty* cells.

Also note that I replaced `Set CurCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)` with `curCellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value`. You don't need to `Set` an object in every iteration. Filling the variable suffices.

But: this will check for all `msoOLEControlObject`s which includes checkboxes, textboxes and the like.

HTH.